# What does Mai's weird hand gesture joke even mean?

Tags: nichijou

[image: hand gesture of Mai at episode 17]

At episode 17 when the teacher asked the students to participate Mai raised her hand like this (shown at photo). What this joke even mean?

Comment: A partial answer is that it's a "fox" hand sign, but without knowing the context (since I don't watch it), I can't guess the implication....

Comment: Looks like it's just something fun and casual! Probably not good for class setting LOL. https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/48367/30386

Comment: In this case, the sign doesn't mean anything. Mai is just fooling around (Nichijou is well known to over dramatize scenes and emotions).